# TFS MSBuild: Combining parallel builds and sequential builds in a single TFS .proj file

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild

I'll lay down the scenario:

1. We have a TFS build .proj that builds 3 dependency solutions sequentially.
2. It then builds about 100 unrelated solutions in parallel.

This seemed to work fine under .net 3.5, however since we've moved to 4.0 it appears that the dependency solutions are build in parallel which is causing issues.

I could always just do an

`<Exec Command="C:\PATH\TO\MSBUILD SOLUTION1">`
`<Exec Command="C:\PATH\TO\MSBUILD SOLUTION2">`
`<Exec Command="C:\PATH\TO\MSBUILD SOLUTION3">`

etc but this seems a bit messy.

So my question: How do I tell MSBUILD to build some solutions in sequence and THEN build loads of others in parallel?

(Our current build pattern is below)

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SolutionToBuild0 Include="$(SolutionRoot)\Solutions\MSBuildTasks\MSbuildTasks.sln"/>

  <SolutionToBuild1 Include="$(SolutionRoot)\Solutions\Level1\Level1.sln" />

  <SolutionToBuild2 Include="$(SolutionRoot)\Solutions\Level2\Level2.sln" />

  <SolutionToBuild3 Include="$(SolutionRoot)\Solutions\xxx.Reporting\xxx.Reporting.sln />
</ItemGroup>

<MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionToBuild0)" Targets="Build" Properties="TeamBuildConstants=$(TeamBuildConstants)" BuildInParallel="false" />

<MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionToBuild1)" Targets="Build" Properties="TeamBuildConstants=$(TeamBuildConstants)" BuildInParallel="false" />
<MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionToBuild2)" Targets="Build" Properties="TeamBuildConstants=$(TeamBuildConstants)" BuildInParallel="false" />
<MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionToBuild3)" Targets="Build" Properties="TeamBuildConstants=$(TeamBuildConstants)" BuildInParallel="false" />
```

```
<SolutionToBuild Include="$(SolutionRoot)\Solutions\xxx.LocationImporter\xxx.LocationImporter.sln" />
<SolutionToBuild Include="$(SolutionRoot)\xxx\Dev\Source\server_and_common2008.sln" />
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned solution dependency, I'm wondering if you can use project reference to solve your problem? If you can specify the dependency of your projects using project references then MSBuild will figure out what it needs to build in parallel and what not.

See if your problem can be solved by the anwers in the Team Build forum:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/80b15488-771e-4b0f-92a3-0175a639286e